# e.Source is not working properly

Tags: wpf, mousedown

In my WPF application am having one Border. Inside that there is a canvas which consists of textbox. And am having mousedown event for each border,canvas and textbox. But while mousedown on text box the event for canvas mousedown will get invoked and the e.source is canvas , it should be textbox. whats wrong with my approach?

Comment: try e.OriginalSource

Comment: Thanks @tabby . But the key down event of textbox doesn't get invoked.When i hit on textbox it is going to canvas 's Mousedown using e.original source am validating that functionality, then it comes to textbox mousedown. but it doesn't go to textbox keydown event.

Comment: Use PreviewMouseDownEvent instead and see

Comment: I have used Preview events only.     Mouse down is working and keydown is not working.                myTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += OnTextBoxKeyDown;
                  
myTextBox.PreviewMouseDown += MyTextBox_MouseDown;

Comment: what exactly do you want, OnTextBoxKeyDown event will fire only when your textbox get focused

Comment: I want to edit the text of textbox on mouse down followed by onkeydown.Thanks it works after set focus to textbox.